# replace everything except specific words in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is it possible to use php's preg_replace to remove anything in a string except specific words?

For example:

```
$text = 'Hello, this is a              test string from php.';
```

I want to remove everything except "test" and "php" so it will be:

```
$text will be 'test php'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a [callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback). Under PHP 5.3:

```
$keep = array('test'=>1, 'php'=>1);

$text = trim(
    preg_replace(
        '/[^A-Za-z]+/', ' ',
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/[A-Za-z]+/',
            function ($matched) use (&keep) {
                if (isset($keep[$matched[0]])) {
                    return $matched[0];
                }
                return '';
            }, $text
            )   )            );
```

Alternatively:

```
$text = 
    array_intersect(
        preg_split('/[^A-Za-z]+/', $text),
        array('test', 'php')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'Hello, this is a              test string from php.';
$words = preg_split('~\W~', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$allowed_words = array('test'=>1, 'php'=>1);
$output = array();
foreach($words as $word)
{
    if(isset($allowed_words[$word]))
    {
        $output[] = $word;
    }
}

print implode(' ', $output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided code, I want to use the function preg_replace. My text is huge and I don't want to loop through all words.

Comment: @AbuSara: a regex must still loop through the whole text.

Comment: @AbuSara, if you text is huge then it's better to pull the words you want out, than to remove the worlds you don't want. `preg_match_all` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/oleksandr-andrushchenko/68d7382fb917dd4eb66ac8ca9bd84006

```
addWordSecrets('Secret all words'), // ****** *** *****
addWordSecrets('Secret all, except; kept, kept2 and kept3 word', excepts: ['kept, kept2', 'kept3']), // ****** ***, ******; kept, kept2 *** kept3 ****
addWordSecrets('Any language & two-way case insensitive: Україна україна', excepts: ['укРАЇна']), // *** ******** & ***-*** **** ***********: Україна україна
addWordSecrets('Percents * percents', excepts: '*', char: '%'), // %%%%%%%% * %%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Atention: The behavior of this function(`preg_replace_callback`) is almost identical to [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). User in question wanted with `preg_replace()`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: User wants "to remove everything except some words", and not change it all to `'*'`.